# Adding an opaque background without overlapping other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a background for a menu opaque without making my list and icon-close button opaque as well. I tried using z-index but it didn't work.

Also the background `div` breaks the link on the icon-close button, so I can't close the menu even though the background div is located under the icon.

#### My Fiddle :

[**Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/og1fqfsd/1/)

#### My HTML code :

```
<div class="menu">
  <!-- Menu icon -->
  <div class="icon-close">
    <i class="fa fa-remove fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Me</li>
    <li>Contact Me</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="background"></div>
</div>
<div id="jumbotron">
  <div id="icon-move">
    <div class="menu-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### My CSS code :

```
#jumbotron {
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url("images/logogreybg.png");
}

.menu-icon {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index:2;
}

.menu-icon i {
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #3C5F7C;
    z-index:2;
}

.icon-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.icon-close i {
    color: darkred;
    z-index:1;
}

.menu {
    left: -300px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
    height: 750px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
}

#background {
    height: 750px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .25;
    margin-top: -307px;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.menu li {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

#### My JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-icon').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);
        $('#jumbotron').animate({
            left: "300px"
        }, 200);
        $('.menu-icon').fadeTo("fast", 0);
    });
    /* Then push them back */
    $('.icon-close').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-300px"
        }, 200);
        $('#jumbotron').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Paulie_D My question is not a duplicate because he answer to that question does not fix the jquery animation breaking in mine.

Comment: If you have two issues you should ask two separate questions.

Comment: I need to wait 90 minutes between asking questions. Kind of tedious when I have time to work on it now and won't later.

Comment: Unfortunate but that's the rules...

Answer (score 1):

Try `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);` instead tag opacity.
I edited your fiddle and works: https://jsfiddle.net/og1fqfsd/2/

Comment: the answer is right, but to preserve the original opacity use `rgba(0,0,0,.25)`. Don't forget to remove the `opacity` rule.

Comment: The icon-close still does not close the menu though. It works without background existing

Comment: Thanks, @LorenzoMarcon.